# (AgoraRTCEngine_iOS) pushExternalVideoFrame returns false

Tags: agora.io

pushExternalVideoFrame returns false although the setExternalVideoSource is set to true.

Normal AgoraCameraSourcePush method does works, but when I switch to my custom push, it fails.
What could be causing this?
Is there any way that I can see a log?

```
func updateClientRole(_ role: AgoraClientRole) {
        print("updateClientRole,", role.title)
        self.role = role
        if role == .broadcaster {
            makeConfig(mirror: false)
            
            agoraKit.enableLocalVideo(true)
            agoraKit.enableLocalAudio(true)
            agoraKit.enableAudioVolumeIndication(250, smooth: 3, report_vad: true)
            agoraKit.setAudioProfile(.speechStandard, scenario: .communication)
            agoraKit.setExternalVideoSource(true, useTexture: true, pushMode: true)
            
// this works
            localVideoView = CustomVideoSourcePreview(frame: view.frame)
            videosView.appendBackgroundViewContainer(uid: myUID, itsTeacher: self.amTeacher).addSubview(localVideoView!)
            customCamera = AgoraCameraSourcePush(delegate: self, videoView: localVideoView!)
            self.customCamera?.startCapture(ofCamera: .front)
            self.localVideoView?.bindFrameToSuperviewBounds()
// this does not work
            let myVideoView = videosView.appendBackgroundViewContainer(uid: myUID, itsTeacher: self.amTeacher)
            avatarView = MyAvatarView(to: myVideoView)
            avatarView?.delegate = self
    }
}


func myVideoCapture(_ capture: AgoraCameraSourcePush?, didOutputSampleBuffer pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, rotation: Int, timeStamp: CMTime) {
        
        let videoFrame = AgoraVideoFrame()
        videoFrame.format = 12
        videoFrame.textureBuf = pixelBuffer
        videoFrame.time = timeStamp
        videoFrame.rotation = Int32(rotation)
        let success = agoraKit?.pushExternalVideoFrame(videoFrame)
        print("myVideoCapture.success",success) -> this print "myVideoCapture.success Optional(false)"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was converting UIImage directly to CVPixelBuffer, but converting UIImage -> CIImage -> CVPixelBuffer magically worked.